# Imprimir resultados de un controlador en una vista en Laravel

Tags: laravel, mvc, php7, laravel-blade, laravel-7

Estoy comenzando a utilizar Laravel y aún no entiendo bien como imprimir en una vista los resultados que son retornados desde un controlador (el cual ejecuta un cálculo de dos variables y una constante).

El algoritmo consiste en enviar desde la vista `calcular.blade.php` los datos através de un formulario al controlador `calculoController` cuya función es `calcularEntradas` dónde se calculará dependiendo el caso las variables recibidas, al obtener el resultado las variables se imprimirán en la misma vista `cacular.blade.php`

Controlador: **calculoController.php:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class calculoController extends Controller
{
    public function calcularEntradas(Request $request)
    {
    $valor1 = $request->input("entrada1");
    $valor2 = $request->input("entrada2");
    $tipo   = $request->input("tipo_entrada");

switch ($tipo) {
  case "Calculo1":
    $resultado = $valor1 * 0.05 + $valor2;
    $tipo;
    break;
  case "Calculo2":
    $resultado = $valor1 * 0.085 + $valor2;
    $tipo;
    break;
  case "Calculo3":
    $resultado = $valor1 * 0.0986 + $valor2;
    $tipo;
    break;  
  case "Calculo4":
    $resultado = $valor1 * 0.135 + $valor2;
    $tipo;
    break;
    default:
    echo "";
     }
    return view('cacular', ['tipo' => $tipo, 'resultado' => $resultado']);
  }
}
```

Vista: views/**calcular.blade.php**

```
    <form action="{{route('enviar_datos')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off" >
                @csrf
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_entrada" value="Calculo1" required>
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_entrada" value="Calculo2" required>        
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_entrada" value="Calculo3" required>
                <input type="radio" name="tipo_entrada" value="Calculo4" required>
                <input type="number" name="valor1" placeholder="Valor 1" required>
                <input type="number" name="valor2" placeholder="Valor 2" required>
                <button> Calcular </button>
    </form>
                <div class="label">
                El tipo de cálculo es: {{ $tipo }}
                El resultado es: {{ $resultado }} 
                </div>
```

Ruta: routes/**web.php**

```
      use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/calculo', function () {
    return view('calcular');
});

Route::post('/calculo', 'calculoController@calcularEntradas')->name('enviar_datos');
```

No tengo muy claro como enviar los datos al controlador, imprimir el resultado a la vista desde el controlador y estructurar las rutas en Laravel.

Versión de PHP: 7.4
Versión de Laravel: 7
Plataforma: Heroku

Error obtenido:

> Undefined variable: `$resultado` y `$tipo`

Comment: si realizaste algún cambio, agrega lo que cambiaste pero mantén lo que habías publicado. para ver el error

Comment: en tu consola agrega esta linea `php artisan route:list` y publica una captura para ver las rutas.

Comment: Los cambios fueron agregados y actualizados en la pregunta. Disculpa no haberlos colocados anteriormente.

Comment: Domain | Method   | URI      | Name         | Action                                              | Middleware |

|        | GET|HEAD | /        |              | Closure                                             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |              | Closure                                             | api          | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login    |              | Closure                                             | web        |
|        | POST     | calcular    | enviar_datos | App\Http\Controllers\calculoController@calcularEntradas | web

Comment: coloca bien el nombre en el `<form>` es `enviar_datos` y lo pusiste `eviar_datos` falto la `n` por eso el error por que esta mal escrito.

Comment: Corregí todo y ahora solo le da error `Undefined variable: $tipo $resultado`

Comment: Laravel tiene una función de ayuda corta específica para mostrar variables  `dd ()` significa "Dump and Die"

te aconsejo que la utilices en el controlador `dd()` para ver si realmente estas obteniendo datos desde el `form` y la lógica que haces en el controlador, utilízala después de las variable1, 2 y tipo y las puedes usar así = dd($valor1. $valor2, $tipo) y luego le das a enviar en el blade y te mostrara unos detalles y buscas en `request`

Comment: el otro consejo que te doy es que mejor te leas la documentación, por que tienes muchas dudas.

Comment: Buenas, amigo no será que el problema se encuentra en calcular.blade.php que cómo intento imprimir las variables $resultado y $tipo no están declaradas, es decir impirmir en la misma de donde envían los datos?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu error sea por esto:

Deberías poner `Request` en el controlador

```
public function calcularEntradas(Request $request){}
```

y para retornar las variables a la vista normalmente yo las envio asi:

```
return view(calcular , [ 'variable1' => $tipo , 'variable2' =>$resultado ]);
```

luego en tu `web.php`

```
Route::post('/calculo', 'calculoController@calcularEntradas')->name('enviar_datos')
```

El `name` se usa para evitar usar toda la linea que ingresas en el `route`, y las puedes utilizar tanto en las vistas como en los controladores(esto es opcional)
en tu caso seria (si la implementas):

```
<form action="{{route('enviar_datos')}}" method="POST">.......</form>
```

En la vista lo utilizar asi:

```
<span>el resultado es: {{$variable1}}</span>
```

o si quieres puedes cambiar el identificador `variable1` por:

```
return view(calcular , [ 'tipo' => $tipo , 'resultado' =>$resultado ]);
```

y el resultado seria lo mismo:

```
<span>el resultado es: {{$tipo}}</span>
```

Comment: Por qué colocar `[ 'variable1' => $tipo` ? Si la variable `tipo` es el tipo de cálculo que se aplicará en el switch case

Comment: es una de las formas que se utiliza para enviar datos a la vista, en el ejemplo agregue `variable1`  pero puede ser esto tambien `['tipo' => $tipo]`

Comment: donde en la vista lo utiliza `{{$variable1}}` (si lo dejas como lo agregué yo). y si gustas como en el comentario seria `{{$tipo}}`, eso ya es cuestion de como lo quieres identificar.

Comment: Entiendo, y en calcular.blade.php se retomarían los datos imprimiendolos ``{{ $tipo }}`` y ``{{ $resultado }}`` ?

Comment: correcto, asi normalmente yo lo hago, en todo caso edite tratando de explicar eso

Comment: Estaba probando y me sale el siguiente error: `Route [eviar_datos] not defined.`

Comment: pude ser por que la ruta `get` y `post`  tienen el mismo "url", utiliza `/calculo-post` en el `Route::post` y me confirmas si te aparece de nuevo el error.

Comment: Sigue arrojando el mismo error. HTTP 500, la ruta no definida.

Comment: tendrías que actualizar la pregunta y agregar lo que utilizas y mostrar el error por que es complicado ayudar asi.

Comment: Listo ya actualice,.el siguiente error este: Route [eviar_datos] not defined. (View: /app/resources/views/calcular.blade.php)

Comment: eso puede ser por que no escribiste bien la ruta. podrías agregar las dos rutas la del get y post porfavor ?

Comment: `Route [eviar_datos] not defined.`  por que escribiste mal el `name` en el action del `form`. es `enviar_datos`

Answer (score 0):

el error es por lo siguiente:
Imaginate que alguien intente ingresar al endpoint /calculo antes de realizar el cálculo en cuestión, esas variables que le pasas desde el controlador nunca existirían.

Por lo tanto, entiendo que podrías inicializar las mismas con un valor de 0 o el valor que te sirva a vos, para que esas variables si estén definidas desde el inicio.. Después de eso podrías implementar tu lógica para lo que necesites, pero en principio, la vista no tiene ninguna variable por lo que vas a recibir ese error siempre.